# Cannot find VS Code application on Elementary OS

Tags: software-installation, vscode

So I just got a fresh install of Elementary OS and wanted to get myself Virtual Studio Code which is the editor I used back when I had Windows.
Googled a how to and did the following (in terminal):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install code --classic
```

All went well and the terminal said that vscode has been installed, but I cannot find the actual applicattion anywhere in the applications section.
What can I do?
Thank you!

UPDATE :
Restarted the pc and the app appeared :/
Does this always happen with Elementary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a snap thing than an eOS thing. In other words, I've seen the same behavior on other operating systems where I'd installed snaps.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910821/programs-installed-via-snap-not-showing-up-in-launcher) is a thread with a bunch of people who had issues getting snaps to show. In my experience, it generally appears in the menus after a reboot (or logging off and back in again) - so long as it was shipped with a proper .desktop file.

Always? No, probably not always. Frequently? Surely it is, if you plan on installing many snaps. For example, see [this particular comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/1201081/453950) from the above linked thread, where they only see their snaps after they logoff and then login again.